# Swiper.js not working correctly, not rendering slide amounts right

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I am trying to achieve a design where each slide is 675px in width, and they overflow off of the right side of the page where each user can swipe.

But, when I hardcode the element to be 675px, swiper.js does not calculate the width correctly unless I pass `slidesPerView={1}`, and then I only see one slide per page and can swipe to see other ones, again, only one per page.

How it looks currently, on `slidesPerView={1}` OR `slidesPerView={auto}`
[image]

How I want it to look (imagine red boxes are filled)
[image]

Here is my code:

`index.js`

```
<section className="projects">
          <div className="container--main-extended">
            <div className="projects__inner">
              <div className="projects__header">
                <Heading subText="Projects">Examples of my work</Heading>
              </div>
              <div className="projects__projectList">
                <Swiper
                  slidesPerView={'auto'}
                  spaceBetween={20}
                  onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
                  onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
                >

                  {projects.map((project) => (
                    <SwiperSlide>
                      <Project project={project} />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                  ))}
                </Swiper>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

`Project.jsx`

```
import ProjectImage from "../atoms/ProjectImage";

const Project = ({ project }) => {
  const techStack = [
    "React",
    "Next.js",
    "TailwindCSS",
    "Framer Motion",
    "TailwindCSS",
  ];

  return (
    <a href="#" class="project__link">
      <div className="project">
        <div className="project__images">
          <ProjectImage
            type={project.imageStype}
            background={project.background}
            images={project.images}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="project__header">
          <h2 className="heading--4 clr--text">{project.name}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="project__techStack">
          <ul>
            {techStack.map((tech) => (
              <li className="project__techStack--item copy--1 clr--text-dark">
                {tech}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="project__desc">
          <p class="copy--1 clr--text">
            Aliquam vitae magna quis est sodales pulvinar. Aenean gravida ac
            dolor ac iaculis. Nullam euismod massa vitae viverra volutpat.
            Quisque ut massa vel nisl tempor fringilla. Mauris purus arcu,
            fermentum id laoreet eu, molestie tincidunt ipsum. Nulla facilisi.
            Vestibulum odio ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

`projects.scss`

```
.projects {
  padding-bottom: rem(500);
  &__projectList {
    // display: flex;
    // gap: rem(20);
  }
}

.project {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  &__link {
    display: block;
    width: 675px;
    height: rem(600);
    background: red;
  }
  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-left: rem(20);
  }
  &__image {
    margin-bottom: rem(30);
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }

  &__header {
    margin-bottom: rem(8);
    height: rem(70);
  }

  &__techStack {
    margin-bottom: rem(24);
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: rem(10);
    }
  }

  &__images {
    height: rem(800);
    background: red;
  }
}

.swiper-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

finally, I am using swiper version 9.0.2

Comment: Do not give hard-coded width to the slides. Try using slidesPerView={2.5} or {3.5}

Comment: I need it to be a hard coded width though to match the design, it needs to be exactly 675px

Comment: Have you tried changing SwiperSlide's style, like `<SwiperSlide style={{ width: 'auto' }}>`